# How to transpose the table in SQL in a specific format?

Tags: sql, pivot

I need to transpose the SQL table in the following format. The data display should be grouped by date and then time and display values corresponding to the time and date.

From:

```
Datetime            | Value 1 | Value 2| Value 3
------------------------------------------------
2018-01-11 00:01:00 | 1.22    | 2.22   | 34.12
2018-01-11 00:02:00 | 2.22    | 3.22   | 43.12
2018-01-11 00:03:00 | 1.22    | 2.22   | 54.12
2018-01-11 23:58:00 | 1.22    | 2.22   | 34.12
2018-01-11 23:59:00 | 1.22    | 2.22   | 34.12
```

to:

```
         |    2018-01-11            |     2018-01-12           |
Time     | Value 1| Value 2| Value 3| Value 1| Value 2| Value 3|
----------------------------------------------------------------    
00:01:00 | 1.22   | 2.22   | 34.12  | 1.22   | 2.22   | 34.12  |
00:02:00 | 2.22   | 3.22   | 54.13  | 2.33   | 4.32   | 54.98  |
23:58:00 | 2.22   | 3.22   | 54.13  | 2.33   | 4.32  | 54.98   |
23:59:00 | 2.22   | 3.22   | 54.13  | 2.33   | 4.32  | 54.98   |
```

Comment: Are these columns, with the names datetime, value1 and value2? How many days do you want in columns? Arbitrary number?

Comment: yes @TomC columns names are datetime, value1, value2 and value3.

Comment: @TomC I need to display 30days where dates will be the colomns and the time will be the rows

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL isn't the right language for this. Do this in your application. But in any case we need to know which database product you are using. "SQL" is just a query language, used by all relational database systems. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Im using MySQL Enterprise version

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in sqlserver like this: Its a combination of a dynamic pivot table and creation of temp tables. There may be a quicker way, but this works.

First create the sample data:

```
create table #t(dt datetime, v1 decimal(5,2), v2 decimal(5,2), v3 decimal(5,2))
insert #t values 
('2018-01-11 00:01:00',1.22,2.22,34.12)
,('2018-01-11 00:02:00',2.22,3.22,43.12)
,('2018-01-11 00:03:00',1.22,2.22,54.12)
,('2018-01-11 23:58:00',1.22,2.22,34.12)
,('2018-01-11 23:59:00',1.22,2.22,34.12)
,('2018-01-12 00:01:00',1.55,5.55,34.15)
,('2018-01-12 00:02:00',5.55,3.55,43.15)
,('2018-01-12 00:03:00',1.55,5.55,54.15)
,('2018-01-12 23:58:00',1.55,5.55,34.15)
,('2018-01-12 23:59:00',1.55,5.55,34.15)
```

Then transpose the columns into rows:

```
create table #t2(t varchar(5), dv varchar(13), v decimal(5,2))
insert #t2
select convert(varchar(5),convert(time,dt)) as t,
    convert(varchar(10),convert(date,dt))+' ' + v as dv,
    case when v='v1' then v1 when v='v2' then v2 when v='v3' then v3 end as v
from #t
cross join (values ('v1'),('v2'),('v3')) as v(v)
```

Then work out the list of columns (combining date and value into columnname)

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols=STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(dv) 
            FROM #t2 c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Then create a dynamic query based on those columns

```
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(MAX);
set @query = 'SELECT t, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select t, dv, v
                from #t2
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(v)
                for dv in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Result: (columns are actually aligned!)

```
t   2018-01-11 v1   2018-01-11 v2   2018-01-11 v3   2018-01-12 v1   2018-01-12 v2   2018-01-12 v3
00:01   1.22    2.22    34.12   1.55    5.55    34.15
00:02   2.22    3.22    43.12   5.55    3.55    43.15
00:03   1.22    2.22    54.12   1.55    5.55    54.15
23:58   1.22    2.22    34.12   1.55    5.55    34.15
23:59   1.22    2.22    34.12   1.55    5.55    34.15
```